# JOIN TABLES in CODEIGNITER ISSUE

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have Fours tables tto join.

[image: Tables in DB]

My model code:

```
public function get_all_customers()
{

    $this->db->select('*, customerID, custstr, CONCAT(custstr, '.', customerID) AS custcode')->from('customers');

$this->db->join('deliverydays', 'customers.DeliveryDaysID = deliverydays.DeliveryDaysID', 'left');
$this->db->join('deliveryman', 'customers.DeliveryPersonID=deliveryman.DeliveryManID');
$this->db->join('reference', 'reference.referenceID=customers.referenceID');
$this->db->order_by('customerID','asc');         
$query = $this->db->get(); 

   return $query->result_array();
}
```

My Controller Code:

```
$customers=$this->customer_model->get_all_customers(); 
$data ['customers'] = $customers;
$this->loadViews("customer_view", $this->global,  $data);
```

View code is:

```
<?php foreach($customers as $customer){?>
             <tr role="row" class="" >
                 <td class="sorting_1"><?php echo $customer->custcode;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $customer->Name;?></td>
                <<td><?php echo $customer->dmName;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $customer->referenceName;?></td>
    </tr><?php }?>
```

**PROBLEM**

Problem is that it is giving errors

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Where is issue? I an not figure it out.

Comment: you getting the value as array format... Make as $query->result()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is cause because you returning data from your model as array format `result_array()` and you retrieving as object in view page.

So Change your model return as following code

```
return $query->result();
```

Hope it will solve...